# Easy way to seal an old plumbing vent

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain-waste-vent, sewer

I plan on buying a house but it has this cleanout and old vent for the plumbing in the basement.  Whoever renovated the basement disconnected the vent and just let air flow into the basement.

[image]

Is there a simple way to seal off this vent so it wont stink in the basement?  Is this a serious issue that needs to be handled by a plumber?

Comment: Be careful with 3 lb mauls.. cast iron is quite brittle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fernco](http://www.fernco.com/plumbing/residential-plumbing/qwik-caps) makes rubber caps that you would put a stainless worm-gear clamp around.  Take your outside diameter measurement to a plumbing supply house.. What your have is a main drain and cleanout wye.  As suggested by dmoore, future plumbing may be connected, though its not a toilet flange.  Its likely the point of exit for the drain system (from the house), as it traverses to the sewer (or septic), to allow the drain to be snaked out, if obstructed.

[image]

Comment: For cast iron, there's also an internal expanding type cap available that I've had to use as the external diameter on the bell joint wasn't an standard size.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew there had to be something I just didn't know the right terms to use to google it.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to be a rough in for a toilet - I could be wrong but picture isn't great.  Just cap it.  How wide is the pipe is will determine what it could be used for.

It isn't your basement drainage pipe because it is raised...  Well I guess it could be but that would be a very bad thing.

Either way it looks like a rough-in for something.  I think toilet/sink combo - I have seen these tied together in older homes in the basement- but could be for just sink usage - maybe for laundry sink or something like that.  Either way put a cap on it.   The iron ones screw in and you can find them at the big box.  If it doesn't have grooves put some sort of cap over the outside of it.  You do not need a plumber for this.